# Problem with libmyodbc - segfault error

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, mysql

I have an issue with libmyodbc as I am not able to connect to the MySQL database that it is pointing to. When I try from isql I get a "Floating point exception (core dumped)" error, and when I try from R via RODBC I get a segfault "memory not mapped" error. I have tried to reinstall libmyodbc to no avail.

MySQL server is 5.6, and I am running the 14.04.3 LTS Server 64 bit on a intel centrino duo machine with 2GB RAM. It was working for a while but stopped after I did an update/uprade via apt-get.

Any suggestions?
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Just downloaded the MySQL connector from the Oracle website and replaced the libmyodbc.so and libodbcmyS.so with libmysql5a.so and libmysql5S.so and now everything works.